# How to say "database migration" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I work in IT, and database migration is something common in my field. I want to know how to say it.
I have checked on google translate and it tells me:

> Datenbank-Migration

or

> Datenbankmigration

I have asked to some Austrians, but unfortunately they not work in IT, and they have told me they are not sure.

Comment: Was lässt Dich denken die Vorschläge von Google-Translate seien falsch?

Comment: Wenn Du nicht wissen willst, wie man sagt, sondern wie man es schreibt, solltest Du entsprechend fragen.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a question of working in IT or not. It is rather a question of style and good practice in (print) publishing or typesetting.

From a professional typesetting perspective (= How would this be set in a good book?) *Datenbankmigration* seems preferable because it supports fluent reading (no artificial stops inside the word).

However, *Datenbank-Migration* is a possible spelling, too.

Which to prefer - this depends on considerations such as is the audience accustomed to the word (then *Datenbankmigration*); an audience not familiar with the word may find *Datenbankmigration* a little bit difficult to read, and for such an audience it may be appropriate to put the hyphen in-between.

The scientific background is that reading with human eyes and brains is not like adding one letter to another (as a computer would) until something meaningful appears, but rather recognizing entire patterns at once such as a word or a cluster of words up to an entire line. Recognizing a pattern at once is like recognizing faces.[1] For this type of reading *Datenbankmigration* is not a difficult mess of letters but a clear pattern that will be recognized instantly. But of course the reader must have the pattern stored in his brain in order to be able to recognize it.

For first-time readers, on the other hand, *Datenbank-Migration* will be more easy to de-cypher. (Requiring, of course, that at least the patterns *Datenbank* and *Migration* are available in the storage.)

Of course, most texts mentioning *Datenbankmigration* are written for people who know what that is, so *Datenbankmigration* will probably be more frequently met out there in the wild; or should be.

You could also say

> Datenbankumzug
>
> Datenbank-Umzug
>
> Umzug der Datenbank

However, most IT people stick to their beloved English terminology, therefore *Datenbankumzug* (and derivatives) is rare.

---

[1] Think of *type face* here.

Comment: It is a question of IT since there may be a special term for this. Datenbank(-)Migration war ja nur das, was der OP bei seiner Suche bereits gefunden hatte.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann which one will be more appropriated for CV?

Comment: @Jeff. I would prefer *Datenbankmigration* because people reading the CV will probably be used to the word. And even if not - no problem anyway. But if you prefer *Datenbank-Migration* nobody will complain, either.

Comment: @Robert - Ich habe ein paar Jahre lang ein Datenbankprojekt geleitet. Mir ist nicht aufgefallen, dass zwischen *Datenbankmigration* und *Datenbank-Migration* eine Unterscheidung getroffen würde à la "So sagt's der Fachmann und so nicht".

Comment: Mir fällt auf, dass immer weniger Leute den Unterschied zwischen sagen und schreiben nicht treffen.

Comment: @UserUnknown - Ja, wenn man pingelig wäre, müsste es "So schreibt's der Fachmann" heißen. Aber andererseits: Der Ausdruck ist ohnehin ein praktisch gänzlich mündlicher, und in legerer mündlicher Sprache sagt man praktisch nie "schreibt". Ach, übrigens: es heißt ja auch "es heißt", obwohl *jemanden heißen* ja zunächst eine mündliche, keine schriftliche Tätigkeit ist. Vielleicht kann *sagen* dann auch gelegentlich eine schriftliche Tätigkeit heißen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Nein. Was ein Ausdruck mal geheißen hat ist für Sprachwissenschaftler interessant. Für Sprecher und Schreiber heute ist nur von Belang, was es heute heißt. Da es hier um Sprache geht, und es oft erhebliche Unterschiede gibt, zwischen dem, was man sagt, und dem, was man schreiben würde, außer es wäre ein Text der wiederum mündliche Rede enthält, ist die Unterscheidung wichtig.

Comment: @UserUnknown. - Nun, wenn du sagst...

Answer (score 2):

Both should be correct.

A good read on when to use the hyphen:
http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich

> Man kann einen Bindestrich in unübersichtlichen Zusammensetzungen setzen <§ 45 (2)>.
>
> Mehrzweck-Küchenmaschine
>
> Lotto-Annahmestelle
>
> Umsatzsteuer-Tabelle

Nonetheless, you can find plenty of german literature (including literature from universities) using the word "Datenbankmigration" as one word, if you look it up on google.

**Edit:**

I assumed, you understand german. Should that not be the case;

You may use a hyphen for confusing compositions of words.

Comment: I speak little german, you told me both should be correct, which one will be better for a CV?

Comment: I would personally use "Datenbankmigration", but that's just my preference.
The term itself is perfectly correct and commonly used in IT.